# Is there a good way to import XMP data into a spreadsheet?

Tags: metadata, import, automation, xmp

I have 20,000+ images in Expression Media, which I also use to store the caption information. This information is compatible with Photoshop's IPTC information and is available in XMP sidecar files.

I am working on a website and want to be able to include this information with the photographs on the website. Since I can import information from a spreadsheet, I am looking for a convenient way to extract the desired data from the XMP file. Is anyone aware of a way to automate such a process?

If so I am all ears!

Thanks.

Comment: (I think the question is a bit offtopic here.) XMP-files are basically XML-files. Is your intent to manually copy the information from the spreadsheet to the website? Then asking for "`XML` to `your favourite spreadsheet format`" converters on Super User might help. If you want the website automatically read the XMP-files, you could parse them e.g. with PHP and ask for help in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Koiyu, Thanks for the advice. I will take it over there.

Comment: I agree with the off-topic assessment. Sure, it's photo-related, but approach to handling these XML files is no different than from any other XML file (which is kind of the point.)

Comment: Off-topic but still interesting to photographer-programmers. I have done something similar. Inspect the XML to determine the structure. Write a PHP program to parse the XML data and write it into a MySQL database so that you can quickly retrieve it when displaying the photos. The XML tools in PHP are easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Phil Harvey's tool and I must admit that the beauty and functionality was lost on me. I suppose it is great if you are handy with the command line. This prompted me to look further and I finally found what I was looking for all along.

I use **Expression Media** for cataloging all my photographs and I finally found the feature that I needed in the beginning. Under **Make** there is a feature called **Text Data File...** In it you can select all the fields you desire to extract from and it outputs the results into a .txt or .csv file which I can then import into my website.

Problem completely solved. And I couldn't be happier about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Phil Harvey's exiftool, which can extract not just Exif data but a lot of other data formats from image files.

Download exiftool from http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Note the XMP documentation on http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html